# How to validate date in SOAP request message

Tags: wcf, soap, soapui

I have a wcfservice where it gets request and sends a response.
In the request object one of my element is of type DateTime.
When i am passing correct format of DateTime(eg:2012-12-30),the response object works fine and there are no issues.
But when i pass the element in correct format(eg: 201-12-30),the service gives exception and throws invalid date format exception.

Correct request:

```
<req:paymentDateDate>2012-12-12</req:paymentDateDate>
```

Bad request

```
<req:paymentDateDate>2012-12-12</req:paymentDateDate>
```

and the response will be

```
<InnerException i:nil="true"/>
                 <Message>String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.</Message>
```

how to validate it from code,I am validating for mindate as following:

```
  else if (request.paymentRequest.payment.paymentDateDate == DateTime.MinValue )
            {
                FaultException fx = BillPayFaultResponse(request, "Schema Validation Failed", "Invalid content,element 'paymentDateDate' is required,but not found.");
                throw fx;
            }
```

how to validate for whether my service is receiving valid datetime string or not

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to check your date for being in some date range, it is better for you to implement **[IParameterInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iparameterinspector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**. It will allow you to check parameters both on client and service sides.

**Here is an example of DateTime Validation**:

*IParameterInspector & IOperationBehavior implementations:*

```
public class DateTimeParameterInspector: IParameterInspector
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (DateTimeParameterInspector));
    private static readonly DateTime MinDateTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
    private static readonly DateTime MaxDateTime = new DateTime(2100, 1, 1);

    private readonly int[] _paramIndecies;
    public DateTimeParameterInspector(params int[] paramIndex)
    {
        _paramIndecies = paramIndex;
    }

    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var paramIndex in _paramIndecies)
            {
                if (inputs.Length > paramIndex)
                {
                    var dt = (DateTime) inputs[paramIndex];

                    if (dt < MinDateTime || dt > MaxDateTime)
                    {
                        var errorMessage = String.Format(
                            "Invalid date format. Operation name: {0}, param index{1}", operationName, paramIndex);
                        Logger.Error(errorMessage);
                        throw new FaultException(errorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(InvalidCastException exception)
        {
            Logger.Error("Invalid parameter type", exception);
            throw new FaultException(
                   "Invalid parameter type");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    { }
}

public class DateTimeInspectorAttrubute: Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    private readonly int[] _paramIndecies;

    public DateTimeInspectorAttrubute(params int[] indecies)
    {
        _paramIndecies = indecies;
    }

    public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new DateTimeParameterInspector(_paramIndecies));
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, ClientOperation clientOperation)
    {
        clientOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(new DateTimeParameterInspector(_paramIndecies));
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }
}
```

Here is an example of our parameter inspector usage:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPricingService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [DateTimeInspectorAttrubute(0, 1)]
    string GetPrice(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);

}
public class PricingService : IPricingService
{
    public string GetPrice(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return "result";
    }
}
```

In case you can have you your soap message invalide date, and you want to check it, you have to refer to **[IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx)**

*To make the code to be compliled you have to reference System.ServiceModel, log4net (you can find it in nuget repository)*